# Tag creation date tooltip is wrong

Tags: bug, tags

The tooltip for tag creation dates is wrong. I don't know what date it shows, but it's not the creation date. I'm pretty sure that the label itself is correct, just the tooltip containing the date is wrong.

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/weather-api/info created 8 years ago, tooltip says 2014-04-15 10:44:43Z

  > [image: weather-api ui][image: weather-api code]
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info created 9 years, 1 month ago, tooltip says 2010-07-22 11:37:35Z

  > [image: c ui][image: c code]

Comment: I think that ^ is the same issue but it took me a while to find where you saw those timestamps so maybe your report is about a similar issue on a different element. Need screenshots with red freehand circles in that case

Comment: @rene I've clarified the first paragraph and added screenshots with red freehand circles. I didn't manage to take a screenshot with the tooltips showing, but they contain the content of the `title="..."` attribute.

Comment: @rene It *is* the same issue indeed. I didn't read Shog's answer at first.